# Automatic version bumping on Azure DevOps (like Jenkins+Maven)

Tags: go, azure-devops

In Jenkins+Maven, there is the possibility to automatically bump the version of software using a plugin. For example, the current version in the `pom.xml` might be `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. When the plugin is used, it will change the version in the `pom.xml` to `1.0.0`, commit that change, tag the commit, perform a build, publish the artifact, change the version in the `pom.xml` to `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, commit and push that change.

I would like to do something similar in a Go project on Azure DevOps, and before writing my own script that would do that, I wonder if there is something ready-made like this available on Azure DevOps already.

Comment: I attempted a similar Go project using libgit2, and didn't get far. I am thinking of trying again using git2go. You can find non-working code here if you are interested: https://github.com/msound/tagger